# Raspberry pi to sense voltages 12 to 24, what buffer is good?

Tags: optoelectronics

Hello I’m looking to use my raspberry pi in an automotive application where it will be used to detect when the vehicles ignition is activated and de activated. I would like the system to be 24 volt tolerant just to maintain application flexibility. I was thinking something like a buffer which would translate input voltages 12 to 24 to 3.3v logic for the raspberry Pi to detect. What’s the most suitable hardware or circuit to use? Regards

Comment: Unclear whether this is for an analog input or digital input. What signal do you look at to detect ignition?

Comment: Signal will be digital. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Resistor divider with a diode clamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEeFiZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How will this be with constant 24 volts? Thanks

Comment: It won't be. This just scales down any signal between 0 and 24V to a range between 0 and 3.3V. Your clarification for a constant 24V signal does not make sense because a constant signal carries no information and is useless.